# How does the new Google Maps use the iPhone's hardware to figure out which direction the user is facing?

Tags: iphone, google-maps

The new Google Maps app allows you to select a destination, and then go into a mode where the map is constantly rotated in the direction you're facing, and it never asks you to calibrate the compass. If you spin in a circle, the map will spin with you, accurately rotating the map so that the direction you're facing always correlates with "up" on the map. As far as I know, this wasn't possible before.  How do they do this?

The compass requires you to calibrate when you open it, but for some reason Google maps does not.

Answer (score 0):

Modern phones have sensors, Accelerometer and Gyroscope, which are used to detect changes in its orientation, dimension, and acceleration (maybe other stuff too). It probably processes the information from the sensors and orients the map accordingly. I believe [Compass Mode](https://support.google.com/gmm/answer/2839801?hl=en) has been in Google Maps for a while though.